# Let's avoid editing the following questions if possible

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, policies, specific-question

There's two ways I considered doing this.

- One is by making a community-wiki answer so that anyone who wants to add or remove questions from this list, can do so freely.
- Another option would be to have each question and the rationale for having it on this list, given as an answer to this post, so that each answer can be upvoted or downvoted according to whether or not the rest of the community members want to agree or disagree with having the specified question on the list.

I've decided to start with the first option since it's simpler, and if some questions in the list become a source of contention among community members, we can always switch to doing the other option.

Answer (score 3):

- **[Why does the Wolff algorithm slow down in a 4-body Ising model?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1733/5)**

  - **Reasons**: 
     The question can basically only be answered by the author of the paper in question. Bumping it up will therefore not help at all, and all it will do is make other people's (often new users') questions get less attention. Nike Dattani has pledged to contact the authors of the paper when he gets enough time.
- **[Where/when did the fields of Operations Research and Spin Physics or Molecular Dynamics begin to cross-pollinate?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/136/5)**

  - **Reasons**: 
     (1) The asker (Nike Dattani) would like other people's questions to get more attention. For this reason, the question was even closed for a long time, and Nike doesn't mind it getting closed again if the unanswered queue gets relatively large (for example, if it gets back to 10% of the total open questions) again. 
     (2) Bumping it up more is unlikely to lead to an answer any faster than it would otherwise get. It already shows up at the top of the list of unanswered questions due to being the most upvoted of them.
- **[How to choose the values of J and spin parameters in a heterogeneous spin system?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1678/5)**

  - **Reasons**: 
    (1) It's already been bumped up on 23 March 2021 and 30 November 2021 (it was asked in July 2020).  
     (2) Bumping it up more is unlikely to lead to an answer since this question is the second oldest open question currently (1yr 5 months old) and two users left comments but then were reluctant to pleas for turning those comments into answers.
- **[What are the ways to add dynamic correlation to an MCSCF wavefunction?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1685/5)**

  - **Reasons**: 
     (1) The asker (Nike Dattani) would like other people's questions to get more attention. 
     (2) Bumping it up more is unlikely to lead to an answer any faster than it would otherwise get, it's a question that many of us can answer, but would need to spend time typing out something that doesn't advance our own knowledge in the way we're currently motivated to do so (Nike Dattani can write an answer one day when he has enough time).
- **[What are some DMRG packages with an easy learning curve?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1732/5)**

  - **Reasons**: 
     It seems like an easy question for which anyone with experience doing DMRG for such calculations, could write an answer in the [one-topic-per-answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-topic-per-answer)/[software-recommendations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) format, but no one has felt inclined yet to do so. Someone will answer this when they feel like it, and the drawbacks to other users' prospects for having their questions answered, would outweigh the benefits of bumping this question up in terms of the likelihood that this bump-up would lead to the question getting answered.
- **[Interpreting electron localization function (ELF) results](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1721/5)**

  - **Reasons**: 
     This question was bumped up on 11 November 2020, 3 July 2020, and 7 December 2021, and was written on 26 July 2020. It's also had a bounty on it. Bumping it up more is highly unlikely to help lead to an answer, compared to bumping up other newer questions.
- **[How to classify ionic and covalent excited-states?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2085/5)**

  - **Reasons**: 
     Asked in October 2020, it has been bumped up in March 2021 and October 2021 and since those incidents did not lead to an answer, it's unlikely that bumping it up again would lead to an answer more than the likelihood would be for newer questions.
- **[How to convert lab frame quaternions and plane normal to misorientation quaternion and crystal plane normal for grain boundaries?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2356/5)**

  - **Reasons**: 
     It seems the OP can write an answer when they get enough time.
- **[Have FDTD methods made inroads into dynamical simulation of electron and/or X-ray scattering by crystals?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2380/5)**

  - **Reasons**: 
     Already bumped up in 3 separate months, and no comments from anyone other than Nike and OP. The probability of a bump-up helping this question get answered is *relatively* low compared to most other unanswered questions on the site (it might be best to focus on those ones first).
- **[A viscoelastic material with nonconvex memory kernel?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2387/5)**

  - **Reasons**: 
     Already bumped up in 3 separate months, and the question is on a topic that's currently esoteric for the *current* userbase. The probability of a bump-up helping this question get answered is *relatively* low compared to most other unanswered questions on the site (it might be best to focus on those ones first).